# Status 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. Angularjs http

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I have spring controller on the server:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lab/getAlgo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Algo14web  getPicksByLeague(@RequestBody AlgoRequest request) {
    ...
```

Class AlgoRequest:

```
class AlgoRequest{
        public int id;
        public int limit; // I tried change to double and float too
    }
```

And AngularJS :

```
$http.post(urlSer.url+"lab/getAlgo",{id:1,limit:2.5});
```

And when client sent request to server get `Status 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect`

Comment: wonder if `$http.post(urlSer.url+"/lab/getAlgo",{id:1,limit:2.5});` would work

Answer (score 0):

It's because `2.5` isn't an integer.

Your `AlgoRequest` class requires the `limit` field to be an integer, but you've tried to pass `2.5` in. It's syntactically incorrect because you haven't supplied a value that fits the syntax of an integer.

Comment: I change class to  `AlgoRequest{
        public int id;
        public double limit;
    }` , but I still get some message